# What's happening in this approximation for the equation of state of an ideal gas of bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, bosons, quantum-statistics

The way we arrived at the equation of state for an ideal fermion gas was to approximate the right handside of $$\beta PV=\sum_{\vec{p}}\log{(1+fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}})}$$
as $$\frac{V}{h^3}\int \log{(1+fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}})}d^3p$$ This can be readily evaluated.

> EDIT:
> $f=e^{\beta\mu}$, where $\mu$ is the chemical potention, is the fugacity or activity of the gas. 
>  Also recall that the partition function for an ideal gas of bosons is $$\mathscr{Z}(f,V,T)=\prod_{\vec{p}}\left(1-fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}}\right)^g$$
> where $g$ is the degeneracy of the gas. Throughot the calculations it has been set to $1$ for simplicity.

However, when we got to bosons, my professor stated that we now had a problem, seeing as $$\beta PV=\sum_{\vec{p}}\log{(1-fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}})}$$
would diverge if $f=1$ when $\vec{p}=0$. His strategy was to separate the sum like $$\sum_{\vec{p}\neq0}\log{(1-fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}})}+\log{(1-f)}$$ and then approximate the remainding sum as $$\frac{V}{h^3}\int \log{(1-fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}})}d^3p$$
I am extremely confused. I neither see how this solved the divergence problem, seeing as the source of the divergence is still there, we just wrote it differently, neither how this is a viable approximation. Shouldn't the sum starting on $1$ be approximated by an integral starting on $1$? When I asked this, my professor stated that when we approximate the sum, the "step" tends to zero between $[0,1]$. But I don't see how that's the case since we did not start the sum at zero. Shouldn't we exclude the whole unitary cube in the integration? I feel like otherwise we're overcounting.

Furthermore, I don't even see the problem. To start with, when calculating the partition function for bosons we argued, by convergence of a sum involved in it, that $fe^{\frac{p^2}{2m}}\lt 1$. Shouldn't this be enough to guarantee convergence of this sum in question?

> EDIT: This was because the partition function for a boson ideal gas, when summing over all the particles, gives $$\mathscr{Z}(f,V,T)=\prod_{\vec{p}}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[fe^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}}\right]^n \right)^g$$
> and that sum converges iff the summand is less that one.

Why are we suddenly acting like $f=1$ when $p=0$ if that violates the inequality necessary for the partition function to converge??

And even if we forget about that, why can't we approximate the sum as an integral in exactly the same fashion as for fermions?? The integral readily converges; my professor calculated it in exactly the same way as the fermion case. What is going on? Can anyone shed some light on this please?

*EDIT*: As per the notes Tobias linked in the comments, new questions arise. Here is an adapted excert of the relevant bits:

> In the thermodynamic limit ($N \rightarrow \infty$, $V \rightarrow \infty$, with $n = N/V = const$), the sums over the wavevector $\vec{k}$ can be replaced by integrals as in the case of the Fermi gas.
> However, here we have to be careful when $\mu$ happens to approach the value $0$ 
>  $$\langle n(\epsilon_0)\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{-\beta \mu}-1}\approx -\frac{1}{\beta \mu} \hspace{3cm} \beta \mu \lt \lt 1 
> $$which means the expectation value for the occupation number of the ground state diverges when $\mu$ approaches zero. The ground state can then be macroscopically occupied. 
> The density of states, which is of order $\sqrt{E}$, vanishes when $E\rightarrow 0$. This is where we encounter a problem. When we substitute the sum by an integral, we get that the ground state has zero weight even though we showed that it can be macroscopically occupied.

The lecturer then proceeds to do the same thing my professor did: integrate over all states and nevertheless add the contribution of the groundstate in the sum.

My questions about this are as follows:

1. The notes seem to imply the problem is not with the diverging of the sum, but with the fact that the ground state is macroscopically occupied in the sum, but not in the integral? Is that the real problem then?
2. Why did the lecturer integrate over all states even though he had already accounted for the ground state?

Comment: I don't understand well the things you quote from your lecture, but let me point out that the sum to integral-transformation for bosons is problematic in the case of Bose-Einstein condensation. If you want to transform the sum into an integral, then you, roughly speaking, assume that the function $f(p)$ changes smoothly. But e.g. the occupation number $n_{p=0}$ is, usually in BEC, "way larger" than the others, so you miss that if you transform the sum into an integral. It often suffices to split the $p=0$ part from the sum and approximate the rest by an integral.

Comment: I guess my comment is a bit confusing, I'll remove it and try to rephrase. See, in the meanwhile, [this](https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~gros/Vorlesungen/TD/14_Ideal_Bose_gas.pdf).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Is there anything I should clarify in my post?

Comment: You could add what $f$ is, to start with. But I find the explanation by your lecturer very confusing indeed. Read the first few pages of the notes I've linked. I think this essentially is what you are discussing in your classes...?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I read the notes you linked, but I still don't understand what happened in the approximation neither what exactly is the problem. I will update my post to account for the notes and to expand on the details

Comment: To understand this I suggest you put the lecturer's method to one side temporarily and focus on thinking about what the populations actually do at low temperature. The energy gap between ground state and first excited state is non-negligible and the population of the ground state is non-negligible. These facts are accommodated in the sum. Then use any method you like to approximate the sum. A good method is to find the contribution from everything except the ground state (by an approximate integral method) and then simply say the ground state has the rest.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I can sort of get that there is a problem with the ground state. But I'm not understanding exactly what that problem is, and hence how that affects any of the methods I'd use to approximate the sum

Comment: It's not so much that the ground state is problematic as that the method of approximation is problematic. At low $T$ the chemical potential $\mu$ is very close to the ground state energy. It can't be exactly equal to the ground state energy $\epsilon_g$, but for levels other than the ground state it is a good approximation to say $\mu \simeq \epsilon_g$ which simplifies the calculation. Then you find the ground state population (it is everything not located elsewhere) and from that you can also deduce what the chemical potential must have been really.

Answer (score 1):

A few things have dawned on me, enough to make me feel like I understand the answer to my own question, with the help of the comments. So to any that may need it, here is what I have concluded.

First of all, I believe my teacher was wrong in saying that the problem is that the sum diverges when $f\rightarrow 1$. This is evident, but it cannot be solved and doesn't represent a real problem, since, for bosons, $$fe^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}}\lt 1$$
So $f$ can never equal $1$, even if it can approach it.

No, the problem doesn't seem to come from this, but rather from the fact that the ground state energy for bosons is "way larger" than the others, like Tobias said in the comments. When we approximate a sum by an integral, this approximation will only be suitable if the function is slowly varying. I believe this is what Tobias meant by smooth. We can see that this is not the case by comparing the first two terms in the sum, $$\log{(1-f)}\hspace{2cm} \log{\left(1-fe^{-\beta \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{m L^2}}\right)}$$
In the limit of high activity and low temperatures (so high $\beta$) the difference in these two terms is not negligible. I remark that the first energy level is $\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{m L^2}$ because we're working in a box of side $L$.

Having put that to rest, all that's left is to suitably approximate the sum. We have $$\beta P=\log{(1-f)}+\sum_{\vec{p \neq 0}}(1-fe^{\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}})$$
The summand now is slowly varying, so we can approximate it. Why does the integration occur in all of space? Because we aren't "starting at 1". Indeed we're only excluding the point $\vec{p}=(0,0,0)$, but the "next" points remainding are $(\frac{h}{L},0,0), (0,\frac{h}{L},0), (0,0,\frac{h}{L})$. So we're not removing the unit cube, as I thought and as I had remarked in my question, just the origin. Of course now "decreasing the size of the step" results in integration over all space